# Jquery image variable selector

Tags: jquery, image, variables, selector

I want to bind a click event on a image variable defined in javascript but i am not sure which selector to use

Eg:-

```
var image=new Image();    
image.src=src;
$("image").click(function());
```

can someone please tell me the right syntax to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it easier to work with an `img` node rather than the `Image` object itself:

```
var image = $('<img src="' + src + '" />');
image.click(function(){ 
  // do something awesome
});
```

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're trying to bind a click event to an image that's being transferred to a canvas. In that case, your best bet might be to bind the click event on the canvas and check the mouse coordinates against the coordinates and dimension of the image you've transferred.

Comment: But then how do i place that image in some particular co-ordinates like i could do with the drawImage function

Comment: I'm not sure you can bind a `click` event to an image that's been transferred to a canvas. You could, however, bind the click event on the canvas and check the coordinates against the coordinates and dimension of the image.

Comment: Yeah i guess that's the best possible solution , thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = $('img[src="'+ src +'"]');

$(image).click(function() {
  // stuff
});
```

**OR**

```
var image = new Image();    
image.src=src;
$(image).click(function() {
 // stuff
});
```

You can also try live event if you want to draw image to DOM later like following:

```
var image = new Image();    
image.src=src;
$('body').on('click', image, function() {
  // stuff
});
```

Comment: The image variable that i am using is to be drawn on a canvas and i think that's what the trouble is as none of the basic methods are working.